# How to customize Visual Studio 2015 collapsed method preview box

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, themes, customization

I don't know what the office name of this feature is, but in Visual Studio 2015 you get a neat preview dialog when hovering your mouse over a collapsed method or function. The preview dialog will show the first 20 or so lines of that method/function. What I want to do is customize the background color that preview dialog/popup. I cannot for the life of me find the appropriate Fonts and Colors setting which controls this and I don't know what to look for in the Visual Studio Color Theme Editor either.

Here is a picture of what I am referring to:
[image]

I have a customized dark theme but want to change the sickly, pale brownish-yellow color of the highlighted preview dialog to make the code more readable.

Any suggestions as to what color/theme settings I'd change? I don't want to just apply a different theme. I want to customize my current one.

Comment: I have been struggling with this myself, and curious how I can change this so it can actually be useable